# Android e os layouts

Tags: android

Comecei a programar para android  a pouco tempo porem eu tenho algumas duvidas a respeito dos layouts . ha como eu fazer uma tela sem layout e eu diga onde cada objeto vai ser desenhado?

Comment: Poder pode, mas não é recomendado...

Comment: Tudo que é feito em xml pode ser feito em java. Dá é mais trabalho/código.

Comment: se fosse desenvolver um game para android nao seria possivel fazer com os layouts(relative, horizontal, vertical..) @Wakim

Answer (score 1):

Você quer saber se da pra fazer uma tela sem ao menos existir o XML de layout?
se for isso a resposta é NÃO!

Você pode criar um XML vazio e adicioná-los via código, mas no mínimo um .xml de layout deve existir.

UPDATE~

> Paulo, é possível sim, basta chamar o setContentView passando um
>   ViewGroup qualquer e ir adicionando os Widgets e View's dinamicamente.
>   –  Wakim 1 min atrás

Realmente, é possível, mas não acho que é uma boa ideia.

Comment: Paulo, é possível sim, basta chamar o `setContentView` passando um `ViewGroup` qualquer e ir adicionando os Widgets e View's dinamicamente.